# 50 reputation rule for a comment prevents people from getting valuable information. What can I do?

Tags: discussion, comments

I've often encountered the following situation: Someone posts a question, but the question can not be answered because:

- Some important information is missing. In this case, it would be very helpful to let the questioner know that.
- The issue is caused by a bug but there is no workaround available. However it would still be very useful if someone told the questioner that and maybe posted a link to the corresponding bug report website.

In either of these cases you cannot do this by posting an answer, because it will be downvoted and deleted.

My question is: What can I do in such a case if I have less than 50 reputation? My motivation is to help other people, not to earn reputation (that's only secondary).

Comment: "What can I do?" can't be a feature request. Retagged.

Answer (score 9):

Take a note of the question, then go and find a question or two you *can* provide a good answer(s) for and answer those.

If others agree that they're good answers then you'll soon get the necessary reputation to be able to comment anywhere.

In the mean time find some posts that need cleaning up and suggest some good edits to those. The +2 you get from having an edit accepted will help you on your way too.

When you've got the 50 rep, go back to the original question and add your comment then. Though you may well find that someone else has left the same comment in the mean time.

Comment: The recommendation is not acceptable, if a user has concern about particular problem, not about how to earn reputation on SE site.