# How to comment on a question on another Stack Exchange site I newly joined?

Tags: discussion, reputation, comment-voting

I'm new to the area this question was posted in, and I don't have a "correct" answer to hand, but I want to get them a clue as to why the question is not perhaps the right rabbithole, and namely that webdriver uses a different mechanism for handling browser "alerts" or as the OP seems to hint pop-ups.

How do I leave a comment if I only have not enough rep in this link below?

[Function with the While/Try/Except construction intended to close pop-ups fails](https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/45612/function-with-the-while-try-except-construction-intended-to-close-pop-ups-fails).

I'd hate to give a partial answer like I am hinting at above, am I breaking the rules if I leave a half-answer? It just feels better than nothing, and I don't know when next I will pass this way again.

Curiously I'm unable to even upvote these helpful comments below, which people have notably left as a comment not an answer, which I'm not allowed to leave on other people's posts confusingly.

[50 reputation rule for a comment prevents people from getting valuable information. What can I do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/255890/50-reputation-rule-for-a-comment-prevents-people-from-getting-valuable-informati) is a 5 year old post, I know about it, and I am actually more interested in how does a person who is not an expert go about gaining 50 points when everyone is happy to give my -3 points just for asking. Yes, I know this is a duplicate question, but as I just pointed out, I'm unable to participate in that 5 year old question about this problem. I'm not a very fast typist, how do I gain 50 points? Or should I provide a half-answer and hope I get an upvote? Is that what people are telling me?

Seems, the way to get points, is to answer a question quickly, and keep editing your answer and improving the answer so that you get in there first. Learn the markup language to make your answer easier to read. And then hope the poster comes back and give you a vote later on. Although I miss-trust systems with badges and ranks, this is the best way to help and be helped.

Comment: Earn enough rep to comment.

Comment: From the FAQ: [How do comments work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756), and [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173)

Comment: _"am I breaking the rules if I leave a half-answer?"_ No, not strictly. But you should state that's not the whole story, and some aspects of the question are left out.

Comment: Also note that once you have at least 250 rep at any Stack Exchange site, you will get an association bonus of 100 points rep when you join a new one, so then you can comment everywhere.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Isn't it 200 rep?

Comment: "Also note that once you have at least 250 rep at any Stack Exchange site, you will get an association bonus of 100 points rep, so then you can comment everywhere" THanks, that's probably the most useful nugget, I wish I could give you an upvote @rravra pei

Comment: @Safdar Could well be I didn't check the exact numbers. Ty.

Comment: @ConradB It's stated in one of the linked Q&As. Also if you want to write out my nick in latin, it's _panta rhei_, and pronounced like that.

Comment: The SE system is made to organize complete answers to a given question and comments aren't intended for any type of answer (though sometimes are used that way). So, incomplete answers don't have any proper place to go.

That being said there's a good deal of play in how "partial" an answer can be before it starts accruing downvotes or risks being deleted. From the bit in your question here, it seems your answer would be a form of frame-challenging which is acceptable. The most acceptable form would give a solution that fits your newly changed frame. It's up to you if you want to risk it.

Comment: @ConradB _"Curiously I'm unable to even upvote these helpful comments below"_ I think you need 15 pts rep to do this.

Comment: Looking this up might help https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges

Comment: @ConradB Please don't use something like _/edit_, _/edit2_ etc. in your quesiton. Everyone can see that you've edited your question, and check the revision history to see what exactly was changed. Doing so just adds noise we don't want here.

Comment: Aha, been on this thing for years, and only now do I notice that "edited by" opens a history panel. Thanks for the pointers.

Comment: Yes, they ought to fix all the usability problems (in this case discoverability), e.g. by doing [actual usability testing](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2000/08/09/the-joel-test-12-steps-to-better-code/).